# Vue Test Utils: Missing required prop even when the test on the prop passes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I am building a very basic `increment` and `decrement` quantity component with two buttons and writing tests using *Vue Test Utils*. The issue is that mounting the component with required prop `productId` generates a warning that `productId` is missing. **More strange** is that `wrapper.props('productId')` returns `2` which is what I passed. **Even more strange** is that the test I wrote passes.

I would happily report this as a bug in *vue-test-utils* repository but, I think there might be a straightforward solution to this.

Here's the component **AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity**:

```js
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <button
      :class="`increment-quantity ${buttonClass}`"
      @click="incrementProductQuantity(productId)"
    >
      +
    </button>
    <button
      :class="`decrement-quantity ${buttonClass}`"
      @click="decrementProductQuantity(productId)"
    >
      -
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  props: {
    productId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    buttonClass() {
      return "bg-gray-600 text-white leading-none flex-inline ml-1 w-5 h-5 rounded-full items-center justify-center";
    }
  },
  methods: mapActions("cart", [
    "incrementProductQuantity",
    "decrementProductQuantity"
  ])
};
</script>
```

And, here's the tests I wrote in **AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity.spec.js**:

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity from "@/components/AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity";

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);

let wrapper = null,
  store = null,
  getters = null,
  actions = null;

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});

describe("AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity.vue", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      incrementProductQuantity: jest.fn(),
      decrementProductQuantity: jest.fn()
    };

    getters = {};

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        cart: {
          actions,
          getters,
          namespaced: true
        }
      }
    });
  });

  it("renders the increment and decrement buttons", () => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity, {
      localVue,
      store,
      propsData: {
        productId: "2"
      }
    });

    expect(wrapper.get("button.increment-quantity"));
    expect(wrapper.get("button.decrement-quantity"));
  });

  it("dispatches increment quantity and decrement quantity actions for given product on click", () => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity, {
      localVue,
      store,
      propsData: {
        productId: "2"
      }
    });

    expect(wrapper.props("productId")).toBe("2"); // PASSES

    expect(actions.incrementProductQuantity).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);  // PASSES

    const incrementButton = wrapper.get("button.increment-quantity");

    incrementButton.trigger("click");

    expect(actions.incrementProductQuantity).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.anything(),
      "2"
    );  // PASSES

    expect(actions.decrementProductQuantity).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);  // PASSES

    const decrementButton = wrapper.get("button.decrement-quantity");

    decrementButton.trigger("click");

    expect(actions.decrementProductQuantity).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.anything(),
      "2"
    );  // PASSES
  });
});
```

Here's the output:

```js
 tests/unit/AppItemCartProduct.spec.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
      [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "productId"
      
      found in
      
      ---> <AppGroupButtonItemCartQuantity>
             <Anonymous>
               <Root>


Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       14 passed, 14 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        2.428s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```